# SQL Filter on sum

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, having

Here is my query as it stands and it works:

```
SELECT EXPENDITURES.CNTRT, 
EXPENDITURES.L_CNTRT, 
EXPENDITURES.BE, 
EXPENDITURES.L_BE, 
EXPENDITURES.SPGM_STD, 
EXPENDITURES.L_SPGM, 
EXPENDITURES.CAT, 
EXPENDITURES.L_CAT, 
EXPENDITURES.OCA, 
EXPENDITURES.L_OCA, 
EXPENDITURES.L2, 
EXPENDITURES.L1L5, 
EXPENDITURES.L_L1L5, 
EXPENDITURES.OBJ, 
EXPENDITURES.L_OBJ, 
EXPENDITURES.STFY, 
EXPENDITURES.CF, 
EXPENDITURES.TRNS_AMT, 
EXPENDITURES.MGDT, 
EXPENDITURES.VENDOR_ID_NO, 
EXPENDITURES.VENDOR_LONG_NAME, 
EXPENDITURES.DESCRIPTION, 
EXPENDITURES.INVOICE_NO, 
EXPENDITURES.DN, 
EXPENDITURES.OTHER_DOC_NO, 
EXPENDITURES.PRIM_DOC_NO, 
EXPENDITURES.SECOND_DOC_NO, 
EXPENDITURES.TR
 FROM IDS.EXPENDITURES EXPENDITURES
 WHERE ((EXPENDITURES.BE<>'70212349')) 
AND (EXPENDITURES.OCA LIKE '%C') 
AND (EXPENDITURES.STFY='2017') 
AND (EXPENDITURES.CF<>'C') 
AND ((EXPENDITURES.MGDT<={ts '2016-07-31 00:00:00'}) AND (EXPENDITURES.MGDT>={ts '2016-07-01 00:00:00'}))
```

What I have been asked to do is make it so that, if you only group by the fields up to CF, sum on TRNS_AMT based on that, and the sum of TRNS_AMT <> 0 then return all the other data on those transactions.

I am not an SQL person and had to do all this by hand and would appreciate any help on what I need to do. I tried doing a HAVING and GROUP BY but it wouldn't let me omit all the fields after TRNS_AMT from the GROUP BY, and all those fields after the GROUP BY are causing the problem because they aren't identical for any transaction, thus resulting in no filtering on TRNS_AMT.

---

So, in English, I need to first find what transactions, whose sums grouped together by the first 17 fields, do not equal zero and return all 28 fields on the non-zero results, with their TRNS_AMT unsummed, to the user.

Comment: Please add a tag for the RDBMS that you are using, including version if possible.

Comment: @DeanOC I know it is Oracle because I had to hunt down drivers to connect to it, but that's it. I am just a user, and a sporadic user at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from ( select <list all the columns here>
              , sum(trns_amt) over (partition by cntrt, l_cntrt <etc.>) as tot_trns_amt
       from   ids.expenditures
       where  <all your conditions here>
     )
where tot_trns_amt <> 0;
```

This version of `sum()`, called the "analytic version", allows you to still show all the rows from the base table, AND compute the sum "as if" you were grouping by all those columns - the sum will be the same for all rows that make up a group. Then you filter out the rows where the sum is zero. (You need to do that with analytic functions - there is no analog to the `HAVING` condition, that only exists for the "aggregate version").

When you select everything from just one base table, it is not necessary to prefix column names with the table name (and if you do, give the table a one-letter alias, like `FROM IDS.EXPENDITURES E` and write the columns like `E.CNTRT` to make it easier on the eye).

Comment: @Phicksur - please do follow up if you check the results further and feel that the query isn't working quite right. It is possible I misunderstood one or more of your requirements, or that you misunderstood something in what I wrote. (It is also possible that the computations by hand have errors!) Good luck!

Comment: The first place I would look for reasons for the discrepancy is rounding. If the "manual" check finds additional entries that could be removed, it is possible the actual total (pluses and minuses) is not exactly zero, but perhaps 0.01, and you are looking at the results rounded to the dollar. That can be addressed in the query, the `WHERE` clause can be written to check for `abs(tot_trns_amt) > 0.01`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what DBMS you are querying. I think the bellow would work for SQL server 2012 or newer and maybe oracle but im not sure.

I am using a windowed sum to select the trans amount grouped by the columns you require and then selecting where this is greater than 0.

You could also use a regular sum in a cte and join back to it with the key values but i wasn't sure what these would be.

```
        WITH NonZeroTransactions AS(

            SELECT     TotalTRNSAMT =SUM(TRNS_AMT)OVER(PARTITION BY           
                                                          EXPENDITURES.CNTRT, 
                                                          EXPENDITURES.L_CNTRT, 
                                                          EXPENDITURES.BE, 
                                                          EXPENDITURES.L_BE, 
                                                          EXPENDITURES.SPGM_STD, 
                                                          EXPENDITURES.L_SPGM, 
                                                          EXPENDITURES.CAT, 
                                                          EXPENDITURES.L_CAT, 
                                                          EXPENDITURES.OCA, 
                                                          EXPENDITURES.L_OCA, 
                                                          EXPENDITURES.L2, 
                                                          EXPENDITURES.L1L5, 
                                                          EXPENDITURES.L_L1L5, 
                                                          EXPENDITURES.OBJ, 
                                                          EXPENDITURES.L_OBJ, 
                                                          EXPENDITURES.STFY, 
                                                          EXPENDITURES.CF
                                                       ORDER BY
                                                          EXPENDITURES.CNTRT
                                                       ),
    EXPENDITURES.CNTRT, 
    EXPENDITURES.L_CNTRT, 
    EXPENDITURES.BE, 
    EXPENDITURES.L_BE, 
    EXPENDITURES.SPGM_STD, 
    EXPENDITURES.L_SPGM, 
    EXPENDITURES.CAT, 
    EXPENDITURES.L_CAT, 
    EXPENDITURES.OCA, 
    EXPENDITURES.L_OCA, 
    EXPENDITURES.L2, 
    EXPENDITURES.L1L5, 
    EXPENDITURES.L_L1L5, 
    EXPENDITURES.OBJ, 
    EXPENDITURES.L_OBJ, 
    EXPENDITURES.STFY, 
    EXPENDITURES.CF, 
    EXPENDITURES.TRNS_AMT, 
    EXPENDITURES.MGDT, 
    EXPENDITURES.VENDOR_ID_NO, 
    EXPENDITURES.VENDOR_LONG_NAME, 
    EXPENDITURES.DESCRIPTION, 
    EXPENDITURES.INVOICE_NO, 
    EXPENDITURES.DN, 
    EXPENDITURES.OTHER_DOC_NO, 
    EXPENDITURES.PRIM_DOC_NO, 
    EXPENDITURES.SECOND_DOC_NO, 
    EXPENDITURES.TR
     FROM IDS.EXPENDITURES EXPENDITURES
     WHERE ((EXPENDITURES.BE<>'70212349')) 
    AND (EXPENDITURES.OCA LIKE '%C') 
    AND (EXPENDITURES.STFY='2017') 
    AND (EXPENDITURES.CF<>'C') 
    AND ((EXPENDITURES.MGDT<={ts '2016-07-31 00:00:00'}) AND (EXPENDITURES.MGDT>={ts '2016-07-01 00:00:00'}))
    )
SELECT * FROM nonZeroTransactions 
WHERE TotalTRNSAMT >0
```

Comment: @Phicksur - to find out your Oracle version, please run this statement: `select * from v$version;`. The Oracle version is in the line about Oracle Database.